# Php Mysqli transaction not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code, trying to use transaction.

```
try 
{
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); // Line (1)

  $queries = $query_delete_atividades . $query_insert_atividades . "SET NAMES 'utf8';" . $query_anuncio;

  if ($mysqli->multi_query($queries) === TRUE) {
      $resultado = '[{ "resultado" : "ok"}]';
      return $resultado;
  } else {
      return "";
  }

  $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); // Line (2)
  mysqli_commit($mysqli); // Line (3)

  $query_error = mysqli_error($mysqli);

  if (strlen($query_error) == 0) 
  {
    $resultado = '[{ "resultado" : "ok"}]';
    return $resultado;
  }
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
  mysqli_rollback($mysqli); // Line (4)     
}
```

In the variable $queries I have three types of queries:

- An Update
- A Delete
- Some Inserts

If I comment the lines (1), (2), (3) and (4) all the queries runs correctly (update, delete and inserts).

With those lines uncommented, nothing happens in the database.

My queries are correct and verified.

Is this code correct ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to call [`$mysqli->begin_transaction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)

Comment: No way. Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction will never work with the code you are using till you don't update this code `return` logic of before return `commit`

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($queries) === TRUE) {
  $resultado = '[{ "resultado" : "ok"}]';
  return $resultado;
} else {
  return "";
}
```

As after this code execution you returning control from try block to previous function so to continue with this code with transaction `you need to change commit position` like this:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($queries) === TRUE) {
  $resultado = '[{ "resultado" : "ok"}]';

  mysqli_commit($mysqli); // Line (3)

  /* commit internally sets auto commit to true so $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); // Line (2) not required */
  return $resultado;
} else {
  return "";
}
```